# Delphi FireMonkey KeyboardType error after installing Update2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have just installed Update 2 for Delphi XE2 and rebuilt and tested one FireMonkey iOS application I run.  Ran fine on Windows so I exported to XCode and rebuilt and ran it.

It gave a runtime error `.. exception...ERead Error : .. EKey.KeyboardType: Unknown property`  `EKey` is a `TEdit` control and the project `.lfm` file has this data -

```
object EKey: TEdit
  Position.Point = '(104,104)'
  Width = 57.000000000000000000
  Height = 22.000000000000000000
  TabOrder = 7
  KeyboardType = vktDefault
  Password = False
end
```

I have installed the new `Firemonkey-iOS.dmg` packages on the Mac.  Also installed the new `PAServer` but it comes up as version 1.0.2 which looks unchanged to me...?

Can anyone throw some light on this for me please?

Thanks!

---

This is powerfully frustrating....

I have read the installation instructions again and reperformed the installation of PAServer on Windows, PAServer on the Mac and the Firemonkey iOS tools on the Mac.  Still get the same error message running the application on the iPad simulator on the Mac.  I have checked the dates on files to make sure I am installing the new software and not the old version (files have dates of September 2011) and the installations went as per the book.  However I am concerned that PAServer on the Mac says it is version 1.0.2 - the same as it was before the upgrade as I recall.  Can anyone throw any light on this ... Is the problem with PAServer on the Mac (or on the PC), or the iOS Firemonkey tools, and is version 1.0.2 the correct PAServer version on the Mac?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue...

The problem is that you have updated delphi on the PC, but you haven't updated the mac side.  You need to update FPC (and paserver).

Your post indicates that you have updated, but the version number is the same.  Try reinstalling or finding out why the install failed...

FYI, the keyboard type controls what type of virtual keyboard is popped up when you enter an editiable field, such as a TEdit or TMemo.  (default, numeric etc)

Comment: Thanks Peter, I will revisit that.   I believe the FPC update went through but the PAServer, both on Windows and the Mac is suspect.  I couldn't find the PAServer uninstall on Windows so I put some more work that, and re-do the MAc.